# Conditional SQL Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have to write a. insert statement that looks at a table and inserts a record if the conditions are met.  This is a one time thing so not overly concerned about it being efficient.

the table contains a work breakdown structure for a project ( each project having, a project level(wbs1), a phase level(wbs2) and a task level (wbs3)

that table looks like this

```
  Wbs1    wbs2   wbs3     name
  262                   ProjectA
  262     01            Data Analsys
  262     01      01    Data cleansing
  262     01      02    Data Transforming
```

I need to insert a phase(WBS2) to each project(WBS1) with an insert statement, for example adding a wbs2 "02" to each project(wbs1).

writing the insert statment is no problem and I select the data from the project level since most of it is redundant so no issue there, im just not sure how to have it loop through and add the phase to each project, since there are multiple rows with the same project(wbs1) number

insert statement sample

```
    Insert into dbo.pr ([WBS1],[WBS2],[WBS3],[Name])
      (Select [WBS1],'999',[WBS3],'In-House Expenses'
      from dbo.pr where wbs1 = @ProjectID
      and wbs2 ='')
```

How do i run this statement to inserta row every project?(wbs1)

hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: insert itself can't be made conditional. it has no where clause. but what you're doing would be the way to go. insert from a select result, and the select you CAN make conditional.

Comment: This is a MS SQL 2014 DB.

Comment: If you want to insert records for certain project, remove the second `WHERE` condition. `Insert into dbo.pr ([WBS1],[WBS2],[WBS3],[Name])
      (Select [WBS1],'999',[WBS3],'In-House Expenses'
      from dbo.pr where wbs1 = @ProjectID)` should insert rows for particular project @ProjectID.

Comment: Im not sure whether I understand your question clearly but as long as your insert statement sample does what you want for that particular wbs1 record, it will also function properly for the rest of wbs1 values if you just remove "where wbs1 = @ProjectID" condition.

Comment: how will it know to add one record for each wbs1 value? maybe im missing something really simple here...I was assuming it  have to select each wbs1 and re run the insert statement once for each value, like a loop.

Comment: create trigger in the main table using inserted.value insert in to another table

Comment: are you still interested in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary table with an added RowNumber field and then a WHILE loop to handle the looping over each row. You can then run an IF EXISTS as a criteria check before running the stored procedure. See below for example

```
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

 DECLARE @ProjectId NVARCHAR(50) = '262'

 CREATE TABLE #Temp (RowNumber INT, wbs1 NVARCHAR(255), wbs2 NVARCHAR(255),     wbs3 NVARCHAR(255), name NVARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY wbs1, wbs2, wbs3, name)
,pr.*
FROM pr

select *
from #temp

-- Create loop variables to handle incremeting
DECLARE @Counter INT = 1;
DECLARE @MaxLoop INT = (SELECT COUNT(wbs1) FROM #temp)

WHILE @Counter <= @MaxLoop
BEGIN

-- Use if Exists to check the current looped meets whatever critiera you have
IF EXISTS (SELECT 'true'
    FROM #Temp
    WHERE RowNumber = @Counter
        AND wbs1 = @ProjectId
        AND wbs2 = ''
        )
BEGIN
    Insert into pr (wbs1,wbs2,wbs3,name)
      (Select [WBS1],'999',[WBS3],'In-House Expenses'
      from #temp where RowNumber = @Counter)
END

-- Remember to increment the counter
SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;

END

SELECT *
FROM pr

drop table #temp
```